# Overriding an inner function of a method in python

Tags: python, python-2.6, overriding

That is a kind of best practices question.

I have a class structure with some methods defined. In some cases I want to override a particular part of a method. First thought on that is splitting my method to more atomic pieces and override related parts like below.

```
class myTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def myfunc(self):
        self._do_atomic_job()
        ...
        ...

    def _do_atomic_job(self):
        print "Hello"
```

That is a practical-looking way to solve the problem. But since I have too many parameters that is needed to be transferred to and revieced back from `_do_atomic_job()`, I do not want to pass and retrieve tons of parameters. Other option is setting these parameters as class variables with `self.param_var` etc but those parameters are used in a small part of the code and using `self` is not my preferred way of solving this.

Last option I thought is using inner functions. (I know I will have problems in variable scopes but as I said, this is a best practise and just ignore them and think scope and all things about the inner functions are working as expected)

```
class MyTest2(object):
    mytext = ""

    def myfunc(self):
        def _do_atomic_job():
            mytext = "Hello"
        _do_atomic_job()
        print mytext
```

Lets assume that works as expected. What I want to do is overriding the inner function  `_do_atomic_job()`

```
class MyTest3(MyTest2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTest3, self).__init__()
        self.myfunc._do_atomic_job = self._alt_do_atomic_job  # Of course this do not work!

    def _alt_do_atomic_job(self):
        mytext = "Hollla!"
```

Do what I want to achieve is overriding inherited class' method's inner function `_do_atomic_job`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either factoring `_do_atomic_job()` into a proper method, or maybe factoring it
into its own class seem like the best approach to take. Overriding an inner
function can't work, because you won't have access to the local variable of the
containing method.

You say that `_do_atomic_job()` takes a lot of parameters returns lots of values. Maybe you group some of these parameters into reasonable objects:

```
_do_atomic_job(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) # Separate coordinates
_do_atomic_job(start, end)                     # Better: start/end points
_do_atomic_job(rect)                           # Even better: rectangle
```

If you can't do that, and `_do_atomic_job()` is reasonably self-contained,
you could create helper classes `AtomicJobParams` and `AtomicJobResult`.
An example using [`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/collections.html) instead of classes:

```
AtomicJobParams = namedtuple('AtomicJobParams', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

jobparams = AtomicJobParams(a, b, c, d)
_do_atomic_job(jobparams)                # Returns AtomicJobResult
```

Finally, if the atomic job is self-contained, you can even factor it into its
own class `AtomicJob`.

```
class AtomicJob:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self._do_atomic_job()

    def _do_atomic_job(self):
        ...
        self.result_1 = 42
        self.result_2 = 23
        self.result_3 = 443
```

Overall, this seems more like a code factorization problem. Aim for rather lean
classes that delegate work to helpers where appropriate. Follow the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If values belong together, bundle them up in a value class.

As David Miller (a prominent Linux kernel developer) [recently said](https://plus.google.com/+DavidMiller/posts/CtPzXPx9HP3):

> If you write interfaces with more than 4 or 5 function arguments, it's
>   possible that you and I cannot be friends.

Comment: Using `namedtuples` looks pretty good. Using a helper class looks prettier since it will allow me to split code into smaller parts within the class.

Answer (score 0):

Inner variables are related to where they are defined and not where they are executed. This prints "hello".

```
class MyTest2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        localvariable = "hello"
        def do_atomic_job():
            print localvariable
        self.do_atomic_job = do_atomic_job

    def myfunc(self):
        localvariable = "hollla!"
        self.do_atomic_job()


MyTest2().myfunc()
```

So I can't see any way you could use the local variables without passing them, which is probably the best way to do it.

Note: Passing `locals()` will get you a dict of the variables, this is considered quite bad style though.

Comment: Thanks, but using `locals()`  do not look logical to me too. Also `do_atomic_job()` will do much more than printing something so it would be a complex code too IMO.

Comment: Then you have some style sense :). Like Christian Aichinger says it probably needs some rework. IMO namedtuple is just sweeping the problem under the rug. And I don't see any point to the class. Finding classes with reasonable abstractions like a Rectangle would be good, although if it's only use it to access the init parameters and look smaller in function calls I would question it's use. I'm sure some meaningful methods could be added if it's a worthwhile class.

Comment: yes it is not the absolute solution, so I will wait in expectation of better approaches (:

Comment: A better approach than rethinking the structure as said by Christian Aichinger? I would be surprised.

Comment: I am already refacroting my code, but the thing is, this is a question that I wonder and that is much of a best practice. So I am looking for best possible solution (or workaround) for this kind of situations.